# Getting "The constructor CorsFilter(UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource) is undefined" error

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, spring-boot, cors

While creating the object of `FilterRegistrationBean` in Spring Noot, I am facing the error

```
The constructor CorsFilter(UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource) is undefined.
```

Below is the code snippet for the same.

```java
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean coresFilter()
{
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();    
    CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
    corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    corsConfiguration.addAllowedOriginPattern("*");
    corsConfiguration.addAllowedHeader("Authorization");
    corsConfiguration.addAllowedHeader("Content-Type");
    corsConfiguration.addAllowedHeader("Accept");
    corsConfiguration.addAllowedMethod("POST");
    corsConfiguration.addAllowedMethod("GET");
    corsConfiguration.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");
    corsConfiguration.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
    corsConfiguration.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS");
    corsConfiguration.setMaxAge(3600L);    
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration);    
    FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));  //getting error in this line
    return bean;
}
```

I don't know what is going wrong here, need help.

The entire class is pasted below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

public static final String[] PUBLIC_URLS = {
        "/api/v1/auth/**", 
        "/v3/api-docs",
        "/v2/api-docs",
        "/swagger-resources/**",
        "/swagger-ui/**",
        "/webjars/**"
        };

@Autowired
private CustomUserDetailService customUserDetailService;

@Autowired
private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

@Autowired
private JwtAuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    
    http
    .csrf()
    .disable()
    .authorizeHttpRequests()
    .antMatchers(PUBLIC_URLS).permitAll()
    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET).permitAll()
    .anyRequest()
    .authenticated()
    .and()
    .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(this.authenticationEntryPoint)
    .and()
    .sessionManagement()
    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    
    http.addFilterBefore(this.authenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(this.customUserDetailService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder()
{
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}


@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean coresFilter()
{
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    
    CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
    corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    corsConfiguration.addAllowedOriginPattern("*");
    corsConfiguration.addAllowedHeader("Authorization");
    corsConfiguration.addAllowedHeader("Content-Type");
    corsConfiguration.addAllowedHeader("Accept");
    corsConfiguration.addAllowedMethod("POST");
    corsConfiguration.addAllowedMethod("GET");
    corsConfiguration.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");
    corsConfiguration.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
    corsConfiguration.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS");
    corsConfiguration.setMaxAge(3600L);
    
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration);
    
    
    FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
    return bean;
}
```

}

Here are all the import packages:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.reactive.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

import com.springboot.blog.security.CustomUserDetailService;
import com.springboot.blog.security.JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;
import com.springboot.blog.security.JwtAuthenticationFilter;
```

Comment: What is your version of Spring Boot and/or Spring Framework? Post all class, not just method.

Comment: Post full import packages... I cannot detect you use Spring use Servlet or Reactive.

Comment: pasted all the imports

Answer (score 0):

Because Required type is `CorsConfigurationSource` , but you provided `UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource` . You also cannot cast in this case (I tried).

[image]

If you want create your own Filter, use like this

```java
package com.example.security;

import org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CustomFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

then use like this

```java
package com.example.security;

import com.example.security.jwt.AuthEntryPointJwt;
import com.example.security.jwt.AuthTokenFilter;
import com.example.security.services.UserDetailsServiceImpl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.SecurityWebFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        // securedEnabled = true,
        // jsr250Enabled = true,
        prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;

    @Bean
    public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new AuthTokenFilter();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()

                .antMatchers("/api/test/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        //;

       // .addFilterAfter(new CustomFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class); // <-- Add filter.
    }

}
```

Comment: But UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource implements CorsConfigurationSource internally.

Here is the class definition:

```public class UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource implements CorsConfigurationSource```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved:

package should be org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource and not org.springframework.web.cors.reactive.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It is because some modules in SpringBoot 6 have been **deprecated**. Replace the old code with the **following code** in your **Config file**.

```
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**")
        .allowedOrigins("*")
        .allowedMethods("PUT", "DELETE", "GET", "POST", "OPTIONS")
        .allowedHeaders("Authorization", "Content-Type", "Accept")
        .allowCredentials(true).maxAge(3600);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource and not org.springframework.web.cors.reactive.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource

This worked for me. Change your import to
org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource